# When using the pipe function in R and you are switching order will they change your data set?

Tags: r

So I had a Homework question that asks me to use the pipe function, but I wanted to know if in

general switching order would change my data sets.

This is my homework question:

[image]

The following is my code:

```
#c
iris%>%

  arrange(Petal.Width,Petal.Length)%>%

  select(Species,Petal.Length,Petal.Width)%>%

  head()

#Switch order 

iris%>%

  select(Species,Petal.Length,Petal.Width)%>%

  arrange(Petal.Width,Petal.Length)%>%


  head()
```

In this case, my codes did not change the data set, is this normal if they are being grouped

by the same input?

Thank you in advance!  Also, If my codes are wrong please tell me where I went wrong so I can fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, these will output the same things. You should familiarize yourself with what `select()` and `arrange()` do and this will make sense--note that you aren't "grouping" anything with this code.

Maybe think about it this way: First I have some books on my bookshelf, and I alphabetize them, then put them into a box in the order they are on the shelf. Alternatively, I could put the books into the box in alphabetical order. Either way, if I pull 5 books out of the top of the box, they will be in the same order, right?

Comment: Thank you for helping me visualize it, it makes sense now.